# How to display column created in the SQL correlated subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im working with sql in an intro to databases course, and am having some troubles with a question.

I have a database that needs to be displayed as

```
 ID Name                     Description    Code    MaximumStudents StudentCount
 1  Computer Science 310 SQL    NULL        CS-HU310    10             8
 3  Communications              NULL        COMM113     5              4
 4  English                     NULL        ENG101      4              6
 5  Math                        NULL        MA030       5              3
 6  Electrical                  NULL        ECE230      10             0
```

However when I run the following query

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM Class
    WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ClassStudent.StudentID) AS StudentCount
    FROM ClassStudent
    WHERE ClassID=c.ID);
```

I am unable to get that last "StudentCount" column, even though the subquery is
cycling through the select statement.

Is there a way to get this to work how I intend to?

I tried to add my select statement from the subquery into my list of columns directly after the first select statement, but this is a little repetitive because it would work fine without using the correlated subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the correlated subquery to the `select`:

```
 SELECT c.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cs.StudentID) AS StudentCount
        FROM ClassStudent cs
        WHERE cs.ClassID = c.ID
       )
FROM Class c;
```

`EXISTS` checks if a subquery returns any rows.  An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` *always* returns one row.  Hence, your `WHERE` is doing nothing.  Hence I removed it.

Comment: I think I was a little confused about what makes a correlated subquery, a correlated subquery. Looking at my teachers example, I was under the impression, that it had to be after the WHERE clause in order to be considered as such. Thanks!

Comment: @backwardforward . . . Correlated subqueries are often used in the `WHERE` clause, but they can be used in other parts of the query as well.